# How to get pixel-per-inch value of the screen in XNA?

Tags: xna

Does anybody know the answer to the question above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can get this value. You have no idea what monitor is connected and while there might be drivers that actually know this type it might be a default driver. Either way, this information is not accessible to you.

Also, there might be duplicated displays, TV-output, an overhead projector and whatnot. So, the situation is more complex than the normal situation of a known monitor connected to your rendering window or fullscreen window

Comment: Thanx a lot, although I am not very pleased... I hoped to find some solution... :-)

Comment: I do not know from where the information is collected but there are ways to get it in other frameworks. With WindowForms, there is Graphics.DpiX/Y. On Android is Canvas.Density
I really want it! But did not find it for XNA yet.